# Getting the latest git tag from export-subst

Tags: git, git-tag, gitattributes

I want to get some Git data into the archive generated by `git archive` command.  Adding a line `git_stuff.h export-subst` in `.gitattributes` seems to be the way to do it without requiring additional things to be configured, installed, or make Gitwhatever.com run a script before making an archive.  What I want are hash, short hash, commit date, branch, and tag.  The first three are easy.  I use `$Format: %H$`, `$Format: %h$`, and `$Format: %ci$`.  The fourth is trickier, I can use `$Format: %D$` and filter the result in the program before displaying it.  I have no idea how to do the fifth.  According to [Get latest git tag from the current commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014693/get-latest-git-tag-from-the-current-commit), I can get that using the `%D` substitution as before, but as before, I get only the top line.  The line I want, after removing blank lines, is the first one beginning with `tag:`.  How can I get at that tag info?